# Multiple ADFS SSO authentications in C#/Asp.NET/MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a website, and one of the requirements is to support multiple types of users through single sign-on, both with ADFS. Basically, controller A would restrict access to users that have signed on with SSO issuer A, and controller B restricts access to users that have signed on with SSO issuer B.

The main problem I'm having is after I access controller A, I've already signed on with SSO issuer A. So, when I try to access controller B, the application doesn't redirect to SSO issuer B for another authentication.

Is there a way to trigger another authentication to re-assign Http.Context.User with the new ClaimsPrincipal when accessing a new controller?

Comment: may I ask if you are using any custom attributes for authorization? for example a custom version of the [Authorize] attribute in MVC?

Comment: @CharlesMcIntosh I had originally been following the steps outlined [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh446524.aspx) for Federated Identity with Multiple Partners. This method does use a custom [Authorize] attribute. And this is good because the attribute class can decide which issuer and realm to use based on which controller the user is attempting to access. The only trouble I have with this method is once a user authenticates with issuer A for controller A, attempting to access controller B doesn't trigger another authentication with issuer B.

Comment: I hate to sound argumentative but I have a lot of scenarios where I'm using these custom attributes at the controller level and it seems impossible to avoid them when accessing a controller.  Do you have a debug break point in the AuthorizeCore class and the breakpoint is only hit once or something of that nature?